# Opengl glPush and glPop functions

Tags: opengl

I have read about the glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix function and how they serve as a form of savepoint.  I was trying out simple code that draws a basic cube with a scaling operation before it and I noticed something: if all I have in the draw code is to scale then draw the cube, there is a difference if I used the Push and Pop matrices functions. That is, there is a difference if I used:

```
glPushMatrix(); 
    glScalef (2.0, 0.4, 1.0); 
    glutWireCube (1.0);
glPopMatrix();
```

vs just using:

```
 glScalef (2.0, 0.4, 1.0);         
 glutWireCube (1.0);
```

without the push and pop.

The first will draw the cube correctly while the second code (without the push and pop) very wide on the x-axis - again, this is without any other transformation function before and after.  Why does it do this?

Comment: Did you initialize the matrix stack by the identity matrix at the begin of the render function [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml)? Otherwise the 2nd code would continuously scale the scaled matrix from the previous run of the render loop.

Comment: I see no `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` before your `glPush,glPop` what if `glutWireCube` is changing actual matrix? In such case you might pushing one matrix and popping it to different one ... I do not use GLUT so I do not know how the functions are encoded and behave .... but it is a possibility Also have you check glErrors ? there can be error elsewhere in your code

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, here's what's happening:

```
// initial transform stack: [identity]

// copies last stack item and adds to the stack: [identity][identity]
glPushMatrix();

    // multiply top of stack by scalar matrix: [identity][scale matrix]
    glScalef (2.0, 0.4, 1.0);

    // draw cube with top of stack: [identity][scale matrix]
    glutWireCube (1.0);

// pop the last item off the stack: [identity]
glPopMatrix();

// at this point, on the next loop, the stack will be [identity]
```

As you'll note, the stack's end-state is the same as its begin state.

Here's what's happening in your second example:

**Loop #1**

```
// initial transform stack: [identity]

// multiply top of stack by scalar matrix: [scale matrix]
glScalef (2.0, 0.4, 1.0);
glutWireCube (1.0);

// at this point, on the next loop, the stack will be [scale matrix]
```

**Loop #2**

```
// current transform stack: [scale matrix]

// multiply top of stack by scalar matrix: [scale matrix * scale matrix]
glScalef (2.0, 0.4, 1.0);
glutWireCube (1.0);

// at this point, on the next loop, the stack will be [scale matrix * scale matrix]
```

As you can see, since you're not clearing the transform, it's accumulating the previous transform each iteration.

You can check out [glPushMatrix](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) for more information if it helps.